# How to deny URL access to CanCan(Can) Rails application with AngularJS views?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs, devise, cancan, cancancan

I am building an application in Rails and AngularJS, using devise and Cancancan for authentication/authorisation. So I have set up my abilities, `check_authorisation` in `application_controller.rb`, `load_and_authorize_resource` in my controllers and I am trying to access a page/url rendered by a controller with `cannot :manage, myModel` ability.

I am seeing it failing because of Access Denied on the Rails WEBRick server, but Angular picks up the template and renders it without data.

How can actually deny access in a "view" or "url/link" level If you prefer ?